# $(document.body).on has a queue that builds up?

Tags: jquery

I am making a facility to align text in my app and I am not sure if $(document.body).on has a queue that builds up?

I set

```
$(document.body).on('click','#h2', function() {
if (textaligning == 1) { $(this).css('text-align','center'); }
})
```

then set on the right align icon etc

```
$(document.body).on('click','#h2', function() {
if (textaligning == 1) { $(this).css('text-align','right'); }
})
```

It seems that there are no ill effects and that (document.body).on cancels the previous trigger but yep does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind as many handlers to the event as you wish, jquery will attach them all and all will be fired at once.

Not sure why you'd want more of them if you can put all code in one, but there is indeed no ill effects.

Here is an example, I bind two delegate event handlers, and they are indeed called both when you click the div: http://jsfiddle.net/g2nRZ/

```
$(document).on('click', 'div', function(){alert('first')});
$(document).on('click', 'div', function(){alert('second')});
```

In case one of your handlers cancels the work of the other, it may look like only the second is fired, but the opposite is true. Both do their work.

Comment: Thanks, it does answer the question. Do you think I will make any problems by a build up of the events? What I want to do in my app is working but yes it would be building up the events

Comment: And you a right.. I will be changing my code to turn the CSS command into a java variable the 'right' 'left etc bits.